# Yii2 config params vs class properties

Tags: properties, web-config, yii2

What is better to use:

params in config

```
'modules' => [
    'admin' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\admin\Admin',
        'defaultRoute' => 'question',
        'layout' => 'main.php',
    ], ],
```

or properties in class

```
namespace app\modules\admin;
class Admin extends \yii\base\Module
{

    public $class = 'app\modules\admin\Admin';
    public $defaultRoute ='question';
    public $layout = 'main.php';
...
```

What is the best practise?

Answer (score 2):

For me the best pratice is the firts one.

Is the pratice suggested by Yii2 framework, and It allows you to centralize all major aspects of recurring costs related to the configuration, leaving the class aspects of its behavior are not relevant to the configfurazione framework. In one fell swoop in the first solution all the configuration of the framework is visible.
It is also active from the start without having to invoke the class

Answer (score 0):

Configuration is only for the configuration files. The reason is that you put it in one centralized place. The configuration is used by the whole application and if you change it, you don't change the code in your application.